# Why shopify sends to GA duplication transaction ID with # and without #

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, google-analytics-filters

do you know why in GA analytics reports I see transaction ID with # and without #? All transactions duplicated. Please help me to understand and fix this issue. Thanks

[image]

Comment: This means you send them twice, once with # and once without.

Comment: yes, but it's problem with GA or with Shopify? In Shopify GA connected only once in admin settings

Comment: Surely it is not the fault of Analytics but of those who send them to Analytics in those 2 different types.

Comment: I am curious now. How are you sending the data. Do you have a dataLayer in your additional scripts as well as in your checkout.liquid. Can you show the code from your additional scripts and checkout.liquid?